# EF Core выборка данных

Tags: c#, sqlite3, entity-framework-core

Есть обработчик:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/ingredients/get")]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "startswith")] string startswith = "",
            [FromQuery(Name = "limit")] int limit = 10,
            [FromQuery(Name = "offset")] int offset = 0)
{
    var request = _db.Ingredients.AsQueryable<Ingredient>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startswith))
        request = request.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(startswith.ToLower()));
            
    request = request.Skip(offset);
    request = request.Take(limit);

    return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.ToList()));

}
```

При отсутствии параметров выборки - все работает. `Limit` и `Offset` тоже работают.
Однако, если указывать `startswith`, то что-то идет не так и вываливается пустой ответ при валидном значении `startswith`.

Пример:

```
GET /ingredients/get

[{"Uid":"deee1533-59a8-4b3f-a8fc-19dadd3d4ce7","Name":"Баклажан"},{"Uid":"24e3ae0e-f302-42ed-96d4-d042c7c7bed9","Name":"Яйцо куриное"},{"Uid":"79087d7c-d080-440c-978f-cb17d822794c","Name":"Ветчина"}}]
```

```
GET /ingredients/get?startswith=бак

[]
```

хотя должен был найти баклажан.

Бд: sqlite3

Сгенерированный запрос:

```
SELECT "i"."uid", "i"."name"
FROM "ingredients" AS "i"
WHERE (@__ToLower_0 = '') OR ("i"."name" IS NOT NULL AND (((lower("i"."name") LIKE @__ToLower_0 || '%') AND (substr(lower("i"."name"), 1, length(@__ToLower_0)) = @__ToLower_0)) OR (@__ToLower_0 = '')))
```

При этом, если подставить под переменные из сгенеренного запроса значения и выполнить в `CLI`, то все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- примечание: только с латинскими значениями.

При тестах с кириллицей возникает всё тоже самое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То-есть, сгенерированный запрос на латинице работает, но не в `EF Core`.  При этом, кириллический не работает в обоих случаях.

Подскажите что делать, пожалуйста ^^

Comment: Sqlite не для серверов, используйте полноценную базу, для начала.

Comment: @aepot , при всем уважении — это не ответ. Обычно я юзаю postgre, но в данной задаче необходима легковесная файловая бд. Если у EF есть поддержка Sqlite, значит я могу юзать Sqlite.

Comment: Это был и не ответ, а комментарий. Ответы публикуются отдельными постами. Помимо того, что эта бд однопользовательская, то есть только одно подключение может быть активно одновременно, она еще и однопоточная, то есть вы не можете использовать подключение из нескольких потоков одновременно, то есть как только у сервера станет больше одного клиента, вас ждет сюрприз. База хорошо подходит для десктопного приложения, но не для сервера. Ну ок, вам виднее.

Comment: @aepot, все же вопрос о виде БД не имеет места быть.

Comment: Покажите типы полей таблиц, где у вас кириллица не пролезает.

Comment: Проблемы с кодировкой? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532789/2856962